# What is the reason that r^2 changes when power fit is changed to linear by taking log10 first of independent and dependent variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spss, maple

Say I have a set of data in the form [x_i,y_i] where x_i is the independent variable and y_i the dependent variable.
[x_i,y_i]

```
[58,600],
[84,84],
[114,5000],
[122,5000],
[104,1060],
[106,500],
[46,7100],
[74,5000],
[42,5000],
[86,650],
[114,650],
[128,1000],
[128,200],
[58,50],
[60,20000],
[58,3],
[54,50],
[94,500],
[44,1600],
[82,5000],
[70,1000],
[106,180],
[104,1739],
[86,5000],
[248,700],
[66,1200],
[114,5000],
[40,1850],
[86,5000],
[130,5000],
[110,2580],
[94,2580],
[102,2580],
[26,55],
[36,7100],
[92,2000],
[102,300],
[134,100],
[138,100],
[144,100],
[96,105],
[110,100],
[198,1000],
[196,3000],
[200,2000],
[190,1000],
[202,750],
[54,650],
[148,1420],
[110,2560],
[104,1360],
[114,5000],
[130,2580],
[36,650],
[32,1600],
[106,3940],
[120,2000],
[82,1000],
[106,5000],
[176,120],
[78,1410],
[130,5000],
[100,500],
[150,300],
[114,5000],
[72,1000],
[42,5000],
[218,650],
[214,2000],
[214,1100],
[92,163],
[118,2000],
[68,81],
[40,3250],
[138,5000],
[66,2600]
```

when I run power fit

[image: Power fit Regression out]

Now I take
[log10(x_i),log10(y_i)]

```
   [1.76342799356294,2.77815125038364],
[1.92427928606188,1.92427928606188],
[2.05690485133647,3.69897000433602],
[2.08635983067475,3.69897000433602],
[2.01703333929878,3.02530586526477],
[2.02530586526477,2.69897000433602],
[1.66275783168157,3.85125834871908],
[1.86923171973098,3.69897000433602],
[1.6232492903979,3.69897000433602],
[1.93449845124357,2.81291335664286],
[2.05690485133647,2.81291335664286],
[2.10720996964787,3],
[2.10720996964787,2.30102999566398],
[1.76342799356294,1.69897000433602],
[1.77815125038364,4.30102999566398],
[1.76342799356294,0.477121254719662],
[1.73239375982297,1.69897000433602],
[1.9731278535997,2.69897000433602],
[1.64345267648619,3.20411998265592],
[1.91381385238372,3.69897000433602],
[1.84509804001426,3],
[2.02530586526477,2.25527250510331],
[2.01703333929878,3.24029958200271],
[1.93449845124357,3.69897000433602],
[2.39445168082622,2.84509804001426],
[1.81954393554187,3.07918124604762],
[2.05690485133647,3.69897000433602],
[1.60205999132796,3.26717172840301],
[1.93449845124357,3.69897000433602],
[2.11394335230684,3.69897000433602],
[2.04139268515822,3.41161970596323],
[1.9731278535997,3.41161970596323],
[2.00860017176192,3.41161970596323],
[1.41497334797082,1.74036268949424],
[1.55630250076729,3.85125834871908],
[1.96378782734556,3.30102999566398],
[2.00860017176192,2.47712125471966],
[2.12710479836481,2],
[2.13987908640124,2],
[2.15836249209525,2],
[1.98227123303957,2.02118929906994],
[2.04139268515822,2],
[2.29666519026153,3],
[2.29225607135648,3.47712125471966],
[2.30102999566398,3.30102999566398],
[2.27875360095283,3],
[2.30535136944662,2.8750612633917],
[1.73239375982297,2.81291335664286],
[2.17026171539496,3.15228834438306],
[2.04139268515822,3.40823996531185],
[2.01703333929878,3.13353890837022],
[2.05690485133647,3.69897000433602],
[2.11394335230684,3.41161970596323],
[1.55630250076729,2.81291335664286],
[1.50514997831991,3.20411998265592],
[2.02530586526477,3.59549622182557],
[2.07918124604762,3.30102999566398],
[1.91381385238372,3],
[2.02530586526477,3.69897000433602],
[2.24551266781415,2.07918124604762],
[1.89209460269048,3.14921911265538],
[2.11394335230684,3.69897000433602],
[2,2.69897000433602],
[2.17609125905568,2.47712125471966],
[2.05690485133647,3.69897000433602],
[1.85733249643127,3],
[1.6232492903979,3.69897000433602],
[2.3384564936046,2.81291335664286],
[2.33041377334919,3.30102999566398],
[2.33041377334919,3.04139268515822],
[1.96378782734556,2.21218760440396],
[2.07188200730613,3.30102999566398],
[1.83250891270624,1.90848501887865],
[1.60205999132796,3.51188336097887],
[2.13987908640124,3.69897000433602],
[1.81954393554187,3.41497334797082]
```

And try to first as linear regression log(y)=a+b*log10(x)

But now the regression runs bad why

[image: Linear after taking log10 on both sides output]

Comment: The two models are totally different.  There is no relationship between the variance of a batch of (positive) data and the variance of their logarithms, so there wouldn't be any relationship in such a regression model, either.  When you think you see a dramatic difference, it ought to be plainly visible in the scatterplots of the data (on linear and log-log axes).

Comment: https://www.real-statistics.com/regression/power-regression/    This website shows a curve which states mostly similar But I may be wrong Figure 3 Trend lines in this website

Comment: That's a poor reference because it does not recognize that the form of the error terms in the models is different -- and that's another important consideration.